# App crashing using Cloudrail 2.7.0 with portal statistics

Tags: android, cloudrail

After appearing to work for a while, cloudrail 2.7.0 is now repeatedly crashing with the following:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: ServiceCode Error in function selfTest at 26
   at com.cloudrail.si.servicecode.Interpreter.run(Unknown Source)
   at com.cloudrail.si.servicecode.Interpreter.callFunction(Unknown Source)
   at com.cloudrail.si.servicecode.InitSelfTest.execute(Unknown Source)
   at com.cloudrail.si.servicecode.InitSelfTest.initTest(Unknown Source)
   at com.cloudrail.si.statistics.InitSelfTestTask.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.cloudrail.si.servicecode.commands.http.RequestCall.execute(Unknown Source)
   at com.cloudrail.si.servicecode.Interpreter.run(Unknown Source)
   at com.cloudrail.si.servicecode.Interpreter.callFunction(Unknown Source)
   at com.cloudrail.si.servicecode.InitSelfTest.execute(Unknown Source)
   at com.cloudrail.si.servicecode.InitSelfTest.initTest(Unknown Source)
   at com.cloudrail.si.statistics.InitSelfTestTask.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried stepping through the code but cannot see the cause. What I can see is that, in InitSelfTest, the following line is not wrapped in at try/catch block and may therefore assume that appContext.getPackageName() is non null?

```
  ip.callFunction("selfTest", new Object[]{interpreterStorage, appContext.getPackageName(), appInfo1.className, appVersionName, appVersionCode});
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved in version 2.7.1. It was reported through github as well: https://github.com/CloudRail/cloudrail-si-android-sdk/issues/38.